# Flatten nested json in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have weather observation data received in JSON which I'd like to flatten.

### One Full Record

- The first location, contains 25 reports, `Rep` in `'Period'`

```py
{'SiteRep': {'DV': {'type': 'Obs',
   'Location': [{'i': '3002',
     'lat': '60.749',
     'lon': '-0.854',
     'name': 'BALTASOUND',
     'Period': [{'Rep': {'$': '1380',
        'D': 'SW',
        'G': '34',
        'H': '79.5',
        'P': '1019',
        'S': '25',
        'T': '7.9',
        'V': '13000',
        'W': '8',
        'Dp': '4.6',
        'Pt': 'F'},
       'type': 'Day',
       'value': '2019-12-31Z'},
      {'Rep': [{'$': '0',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '32',
         'H': '84.0',
         'P': '1018',
         'S': '21',
         'T': '7.5',
         'V': '13000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '5.0',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '60',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '34',
         'H': '81.7',
         'P': '1018',
         'S': '22',
         'T': '7.5',
         'V': '12000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '4.6',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '120',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '36',
         'H': '79.9',
         'P': '1017',
         'S': '24',
         'T': '7.9',
         'V': '11000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '4.7',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '180',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '40',
         'H': '82.3',
         'P': '1016',
         'S': '23',
         'T': '7.5',
         'V': '13000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '4.7',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '240',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '33',
         'H': '84.6',
         'P': '1015',
         'S': '18',
         'T': '8.0',
         'V': '12000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '5.6',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '300',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '33',
         'H': '85.3',
         'P': '1015',
         'S': '24',
         'T': '8.3',
         'V': '11000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.0',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '360',
         'D': 'WSW',
         'G': '41',
         'H': '89.0',
         'P': '1014',
         'S': '30',
         'T': '8.5',
         'V': '8000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.8',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '420',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '43',
         'H': '89.6',
         'P': '1013',
         'S': '28',
         'T': '8.7',
         'V': '7000',
         'W': '7',
         'Dp': '7.1',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '480',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '39',
         'H': '88.4',
         'P': '1013',
         'S': '23',
         'T': '8.7',
         'V': '15000',
         'W': '7',
         'Dp': '6.9',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '540',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '40',
         'H': '84.3',
         'P': '1013',
         'S': '29',
         'T': '9.1',
         'V': '19000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.6',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '600',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '41',
         'H': '85.4',
         'P': '1012',
         'S': '24',
         'T': '8.9',
         'V': '12000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.6',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '660',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '38',
         'H': '84.2',
         'P': '1012',
         'S': '28',
         'T': '9.2',
         'V': '13000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.7',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '720',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '47',
         'H': '83.6',
         'P': '1011',
         'S': '32',
         'T': '9.4',
         'V': '12000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.8',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '780',
         'D': 'WSW',
         'G': '45',
         'H': '84.8',
         'P': '1011',
         'S': '30',
         'T': '9.4',
         'V': '11000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '7.0',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '840',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '43',
         'H': '86.0',
         'P': '1010',
         'S': '28',
         'T': '9.4',
         'V': '11000',
         'W': '7',
         'Dp': '7.2',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '900',
         'D': 'WSW',
         'G': '40',
         'H': '85.4',
         'P': '1009',
         'S': '29',
         'T': '9.4',
         'V': '12000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '7.1',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '960',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '39',
         'H': '86.0',
         'P': '1009',
         'S': '25',
         'T': '9.2',
         'V': '11000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '7.0',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '1020',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '33',
         'H': '87.8',
         'P': '1009',
         'S': '23',
         'T': '8.9',
         'V': '11000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '7.0',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '1080',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '36',
         'H': '85.5',
         'P': '1008',
         'S': '23',
         'T': '8.9',
         'V': '11000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.6',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '1140',
         'D': 'SW',
         'G': '40',
         'H': '86.6',
         'P': '1007',
         'S': '28',
         'T': '8.8',
         'V': '14000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.7',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '1200',
         'D': 'SSW',
         'G': '39',
         'H': '84.8',
         'P': '1006',
         'S': '28',
         'T': '8.8',
         'V': '13000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.4',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '1260',
         'D': 'SSW',
         'G': '37',
         'H': '87.7',
         'P': '1005',
         'S': '26',
         'T': '8.0',
         'V': '15000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.1',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '1320',
         'D': 'S',
         'G': '37',
         'H': '88.4',
         'P': '1003',
         'S': '24',
         'T': '8.0',
         'V': '13000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.2',
         'Pt': 'F'},
        {'$': '1380',
         'D': 'S',
         'G': '38',
         'H': '89.6',
         'P': '1002',
         'S': '29',
         'T': '7.6',
         'V': '11000',
         'W': '8',
         'Dp': '6.0',
         'Pt': 'F'}],
       'type': 'Day',
       'value': '2020-01-01Z'}]}]}}}
```

The structure of JSON looks like this where each period has two reports:

```
SiteRep - DV - Location - Period (0) - Rep (0)
                                     - Rep(1)
                          Period (1) - Rep (0)
                                      - Rep(1)
```

The desired output would be  the table where Location, Period and Report values are flattened.

```
| i | lat | lon  |  name |country | continent| elevation| name |Rep(0)$| Rep(0)D|Rep(0)G|..
|---|-----|------|-------|--------|----------|----------|------|-------|--------|-------|..
|   |     |      |       |        |          |          |      |       |        |        |
```

I've managed to get Location flattened

```
normalised_data = pd.json_normalize(df['observations'], record_path=['SiteRep','DV','Location'])
```

so now my data looks like

```py
      i     lat     lon                 name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Period   country continent elevation
0  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND                        [{'Rep': {'$': '1380', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '34', 'H': '79.5', 'P': '1019', 'S': '25', 'T': '7.9', 'V': '13000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '4.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2019-12-31Z'}, {'Rep': [{'$': '0', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '32', 'H': '84.0', 'P': '1018', 'S': '21', 'T': '7.5', 'V': '13000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '60', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '34', 'H': '81.7', 'P': '1018', 'S': '22', 'T': '7.5', 'V': '12000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '4.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '120', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '36', 'H': '79.9', 'P': '1017', 'S': '24', 'T': '7.9', 'V': '11000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '4.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '180', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '40', 'H': '82.3', 'P': '1016', 'S': '23', 'T': '7.5', 'V': '13000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '4.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '240', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '33', 'H': '84.6', 'P': '1015', 'S': '18', 'T': '8.0', 'V': '12000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '300', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '33', 'H': '85.3', 'P': '1015', 'S': '24', 'T': '8.3', 'V': '11000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '360', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '41', 'H': '89.0', 'P': '1014', 'S': '30', 'T': '8.5', 'V': '8000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '420', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '43', 'H': '89.6', 'P': '1013', 'S': '28', 'T': '8.7', 'V': '7000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '7.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '480', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '39', 'H': '88.4', 'P': '1013', 'S': '23', 'T': '8.7', 'V': '15000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.9', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '540', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '40', 'H': '84.3', 'P': '1013', 'S': '29', 'T': '9.1', 'V': '19000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '600', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '41', 'H': '85.4', 'P': '1012', 'S': '24', 'T': '8.9', 'V': '12000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '660', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '38', 'H': '84.2', 'P': '1012', 'S': '28', 'T': '9.2', 'V': '13000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '720', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '47', 'H': '83.6', 'P': '1011', 'S': '32', 'T': '9.4', 'V': '12000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '780', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '45', 'H': '84.8', 'P': '1011', 'S': '30', 'T': '9.4', 'V': '11000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '840', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '43', 'H': '86.0', 'P': '1010', 'S': '28', 'T': '9.4', 'V': '11000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '7.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '900', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '40', 'H': '85.4', 'P': '1009', 'S': '29', 'T': '9.4', 'V': '12000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '960', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '39', 'H': '86.0', 'P': '1009', 'S': '25', 'T': '9.2', 'V': '11000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1020', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '33', 'H': '87.8', 'P': '1009', 'S': '23', 'T': '8.9', 'V': '11000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1080', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '36', 'H': '85.5', 'P': '1008', 'S': '23', 'T': '8.9', 'V': '11000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1140', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '40', 'H': '86.6', 'P': '1007', 'S': '28', 'T': '8.8', 'V': '14000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1200', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '39', 'H': '84.8', 'P': '1006', 'S': '28', 'T': '8.8', 'V': '13000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.4', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1260', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '37', 'H': '87.7', 'P': '1005', 'S': '26', 'T': '8.0', 'V': '15000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1320', 'D': 'S', 'G': '37', 'H': '88.4', 'P': '1003', 'S': '24', 'T': '8.0', 'V': '13000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1380', 'D': 'S', 'G': '38', 'H': '89.6', 'P': '1002', 'S': '29', 'T': '7.6', 'V': '11000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.0', 'Pt': 'F'}], 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2020-01-01Z'}]  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0
1  3005  60.139  -1.183  LERWICK (S. SCREEN)  [{'Rep': {'$': '1380', 'D': 'W', 'G': '41', 'H': '89.5', 'P': '1020', 'S': '28', 'T': '7.2', 'V': '15000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2019-12-31Z'}, {'Rep': [{'$': '0', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '44', 'H': '88.1', 'P': '1019', 'S': '33', 'T': '6.9', 'V': '15000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '60', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '47', 'H': '90.2', 'P': '1018', 'S': '36', 'T': '6.9', 'V': '15000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.4', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '120', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '52', 'H': '88.8', 'P': '1018', 'S': '32', 'T': '6.9', 'V': '17000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '180', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '47', 'H': '89.4', 'P': '1017', 'S': '34', 'T': '7.4', 'V': '12000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '240', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '51', 'H': '89.4', 'P': '1016', 'S': '38', 'T': '7.4', 'V': '14000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '300', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '48', 'H': '90.8', 'P': '1015', 'S': '33', 'T': '7.7', 'V': '13000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '360', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '49', 'H': '92.0', 'P': '1015', 'S': '34', 'T': '7.9', 'V': '10000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '420', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '47', 'H': '92.1', 'P': '1014', 'S': '38', 'T': '8.0', 'V': '8000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '480', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '48', 'H': '94.0', 'P': '1014', 'S': '34', 'T': '7.9', 'V': '10000', 'W': '11', 'Dp': '7.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '540', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '55', 'H': '90.2', 'P': '1014', 'S': '40', 'T': '8.1', 'V': '12000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '600', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '52', 'H': '88.9', 'P': '1013', 'S': '39', 'T': '8.3', 'V': '15000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '660', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '54', 'H': '90.1', 'P': '1013', 'S': '39', 'T': '8.3', 'V': '12000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '720', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '53', 'H': '90.9', 'P': '1012', 'S': '38', 'T': '8.5', 'V': '15000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '7.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '780', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '53', 'H': '91.5', 'P': '1011', 'S': '39', 'T': '8.5', 'V': '12000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '7.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '840', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '49', 'H': '92.7', 'P': '1011', 'S': '37', 'T': '8.3', 'V': '12000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '7.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '900', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '51', 'H': '89.6', 'P': '1010', 'S': '34', 'T': '8.3', 'V': '12000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '960', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '46', 'H': '88.9', 'P': '1010', 'S': '34', 'T': '8.3', 'V': '15000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1020', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '46', 'H': '86.5', 'P': '1009', 'S': '34', 'T': '8.4', 'V': '18000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1080', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '46', 'H': '84.8', 'P': '1009', 'S': '36', 'T': '8.5', 'V': '18000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1140', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '43', 'H': '88.3', 'P': '1009', 'S': '28', 'T': '7.8', 'V': '18000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1200', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '36', 'H': '88.9', 'P': '1008', 'S': '25', 'T': '7.5', 'V': '20000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1260', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '36', 'H': '88.9', 'P': '1006', 'S': '25', 'T': '7.5', 'V': '15000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1320', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '36', 'H': '89.6', 'P': '1005', 'S': '24', 'T': '7.1', 'V': '13000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.5', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1380', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '38', 'H': '86.4', 'P': '1003', 'S': '28', 'T': '7.2', 'V': '18000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.1', 'Pt': 'F'}], 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2020-01-01Z'}]  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      82.0
2  3008  59.527  -1.628            FAIR ISLE                                                                              [{'Rep': {'$': '1380', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '31', 'H': '83.8', 'P': '1022', 'S': '24', 'T': '6.4', 'V': '17000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '3.9', 'Pt': 'F'}, 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2019-12-31Z'}, {'Rep': [{'$': '0', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '30', 'H': '88.1', 'P': '1022', 'S': '16', 'T': '6.0', 'V': '11000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '4.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '60', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '82.1', 'P': '1021', 'S': '18', 'T': '6.5', 'V': '15000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '3.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '120', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '33', 'H': '74.3', 'P': '1020', 'S': '18', 'T': '6.6', 'V': '24000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '2.4', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '180', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '30', 'H': '79.2', 'P': '1019', 'S': '23', 'T': '6.6', 'V': '20000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '3.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '240', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '31', 'H': '82.6', 'P': '1018', 'S': '21', 'T': '6.5', 'V': '17000', 'W': '2', 'Dp': '3.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '300', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '81.5', 'P': '1018', 'S': '17', 'T': '6.5', 'V': '18000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '3.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '360', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '80.9', 'P': '1018', 'S': '16', 'T': '6.6', 'V': '15000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '3.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '420', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '78.7', 'P': '1017', 'S': '17', 'T': '7.2', 'V': '14000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '3.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '480', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '84.0', 'P': '1017', 'S': '18', 'T': '7.6', 'V': '18000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '540', 'D': 'WSW', 'G': '39', 'H': '84.1', 'P': '1016', 'S': '26', 'T': '8.2', 'V': '17000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '600', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '34', 'H': '78.8', 'P': '1016', 'S': '24', 'T': '8.0', 'V': '16000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '4.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '660', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '29', 'H': '82.3', 'P': '1016', 'S': '21', 'T': '8.1', 'V': '15000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '720', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '30', 'H': '84.7', 'P': '1015', 'S': '18', 'T': '8.2', 'V': '10000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '780', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '30', 'H': '85.3', 'P': '1014', 'S': '23', 'T': '8.1', 'V': '12000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '840', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '32', 'H': '86.5', 'P': '1013', 'S': '23', 'T': '7.9', 'V': '9000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '900', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '33', 'H': '87.0', 'P': '1013', 'S': '22', 'T': '8.0', 'V': '12000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '960', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '31', 'H': '87.7', 'P': '1012', 'S': '22', 'T': '7.9', 'V': '14000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1020', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '31', 'H': '86.5', 'P': '1012', 'S': '22', 'T': '7.9', 'V': '11000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1080', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '32', 'H': '89.0', 'P': '1011', 'S': '21', 'T': '7.7', 'V': '10000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1140', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '33', 'H': '88.9', 'P': '1010', 'S': '25', 'T': '7.8', 'V': '11000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '6.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1200', 'D': 'S', 'G': '36', 'H': '88.3', 'P': '1009', 'S': '26', 'T': '7.5', 'V': '15000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1260', 'D': 'S', 'G': '43', 'H': '83.5', 'P': '1007', 'S': '33', 'T': '7.5', 'V': '15000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '4.9', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1320', 'D': 'S', 'G': '43', 'H': '80.0', 'P': '1006', 'S': '31', 'T': '7.6', 'V': '15000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '4.4', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1380', 'D': 'S', 'G': '45', 'H': '81.3', 'P': '1005', 'S': '30', 'T': '7.5', 'V': '17000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '4.5', 'Pt': 'F'}], 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2020-01-01Z'}]  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      57.0
3  3017  58.954    -2.9             KIRKWALL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [{'Rep': {'$': '1380', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '85.9', 'P': '1022', 'S': '21', 'T': '3.7', 'V': '35000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '1.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2019-12-31Z'}, {'Rep': [{'$': '0', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '84.0', 'P': '1022', 'S': '13', 'T': '3.9', 'V': '35000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '1.5', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '60', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '78.6', 'P': '1021', 'S': '11', 'T': '3.6', 'V': '50000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '0.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '120', 'D': 'SSW', 'H': '79.4', 'P': '1020', 'S': '15', 'T': '3.7', 'V': '55000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '0.5', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '180', 'D': 'SSW', 'H': '80.1', 'P': '1020', 'S': '9', 'T': '4.0', 'V': '45000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '0.9', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '240', 'D': 'S', 'H': '83.9', 'P': '1018', 'S': '10', 'T': '2.6', 'V': '35000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '0.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '300', 'D': 'W', 'H': '81.0', 'P': '1018', 'S': '2', 'T': '2.5', 'V': '45000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '-0.4', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '360', 'D': 'SSW', 'H': '75.3', 'P': '1018', 'S': '10', 'T': '3.8', 'V': '55000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '-0.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '420', 'D': 'SSW', 'H': '80.5', 'P': '1017', 'S': '11', 'T': '3.7', 'V': '50000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '0.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '480', 'D': 'SSW', 'H': '76.7', 'P': '1017', 'S': '16', 'T': '5.2', 'V': '50000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '1.5', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '540', 'D': 'SSW', 'H': '83.7', 'P': '1017', 'S': '14', 'T': '5.6', 'V': '30000', 'W': '2', 'Dp': '3.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '600', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '85.7', 'P': '1016', 'S': '16', 'T': '5.5', 'V': '29000', 'W': '3', 'Dp': '3.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '660', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '79.5', 'P': '1016', 'S': '14', 'T': '7.9', 'V': '35000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '4.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '720', 'D': 'SSW', 'H': '80.0', 'P': '1016', 'S': '16', 'T': '7.8', 'V': '30000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '4.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '780', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '83.4', 'P': '1015', 'S': '18', 'T': '7.6', 'V': '30000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '840', 'D': 'SW', 'H': '82.9', 'P': '1014', 'S': '15', 'T': '7.8', 'V': '40000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '900', 'D': 'SW', 'G': '29', 'H': '84.0', 'P': '1013', 'S': '22', 'T': '7.6', 'V': '40000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '5.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '960', 'D': 'SSW', 'H': '82.9', 'P': '1012', 'S': '18', 'T': '7.1', 'V': '50000', 'W': '0', 'Dp': '4.4', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1020', 'D': 'S', 'H': '86.3', 'P': '1012', 'S': '17', 'T': '6.6', 'V': '26000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '4.5', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1080', 'D': 'S', 'H': '87.5', 'P': '1011', 'S': '21', 'T': '6.3', 'V': '28000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '4.4', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1140', 'D': 'SSW', 'H': '88.1', 'P': '1010', 'S': '19', 'T': '6.4', 'V': '23000', 'W': '2', 'Dp': '4.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1200', 'D': 'S', 'G': '29', 'H': '87.6', 'P': '1009', 'S': '21', 'T': '6.6', 'V': '24000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '4.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1260', 'D': 'S', 'G': '29', 'H': '83.9', 'P': '1007', 'S': '19', 'T': '6.7', 'V': '29000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '4.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1320', 'D': 'S', 'G': '29', 'H': '81.7', 'P': '1006', 'S': '22', 'T': '6.8', 'V': '30000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '3.9', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1380', 'D': 'S', 'G': '31', 'H': '82.4', 'P': '1004', 'S': '24', 'T': '7.1', 'V': '26000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '4.3', 'Pt': 'F'}], 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2020-01-01Z'}]  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      26.0
4  3023  57.358  -7.397     SOUTH UIST RANGE                                                                          [{'Rep': {'$': '1380', 'D': 'S', 'H': '89.4', 'P': '1025', 'S': '22', 'T': '7.3', 'V': '15000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '5.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2019-12-31Z'}, {'Rep': [{'$': '0', 'D': 'S', 'H': '93.3', 'P': '1024', 'S': '19', 'T': '7.3', 'V': '15000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '60', 'D': 'S', 'H': '94.6', 'P': '1023', 'S': '22', 'T': '7.9', 'V': '12000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '120', 'D': 'S', 'G': '33', 'H': '90.2', 'P': '1022', 'S': '26', 'T': '8.5', 'V': '25000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '7.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '180', 'D': 'S', 'G': '39', 'H': '87.7', 'P': '1021', 'S': '29', 'T': '8.1', 'V': '40000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '240', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '39', 'H': '84.7', 'P': '1021', 'S': '29', 'T': '8.5', 'V': '20000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '300', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '43', 'H': '85.9', 'P': '1020', 'S': '31', 'T': '8.5', 'V': '23000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '6.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '360', 'D': 'S', 'G': '38', 'H': '90.8', 'P': '1020', 'S': '25', 'T': '8.5', 'V': '15000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '420', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '38', 'H': '92.0', 'P': '1019', 'S': '26', 'T': '8.4', 'V': '5000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '480', 'D': 'S', 'G': '38', 'H': '97.9', 'P': '1019', 'S': '26', 'T': '8.2', 'V': '3700', 'W': '9', 'Dp': '7.9', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '540', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '41', 'H': '97.9', 'P': '1018', 'S': '30', 'T': '8.4', 'V': '4800', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '8.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '600', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '37', 'H': '95.9', 'P': '1018', 'S': '28', 'T': '8.9', 'V': '11000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '8.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '660', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '38', 'H': '93.4', 'P': '1018', 'S': '28', 'T': '9.1', 'V': '13000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '8.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '720', 'D': 'SSW', 'G': '37', 'H': '92.1', 'P': '1017', 'S': '28', 'T': '9.0', 'V': '15000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.8', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '780', 'D': 'S', 'G': '38', 'H': '90.9', 'P': '1016', 'S': '28', 'T': '9.1', 'V': '9000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.7', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '840', 'D': 'S', 'G': '41', 'H': '87.8', 'P': '1015', 'S': '30', 'T': '9.1', 'V': '19000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.2', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '900', 'D': 'S', 'G': '44', 'H': '87.2', 'P': '1014', 'S': '31', 'T': '9.1', 'V': '18000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '960', 'D': 'S', 'G': '46', 'H': '86.6', 'P': '1013', 'S': '31', 'T': '9.1', 'V': '24000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.0', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1020', 'D': 'S', 'G': '43', 'H': '87.2', 'P': '1012', 'S': '29', 'T': '9.1', 'V': '25000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.1', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1080', 'D': 'S', 'G': '44', 'H': '91.5', 'P': '1011', 'S': '33', 'T': '8.9', 'V': '14000', 'W': '7', 'Dp': '7.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1140', 'D': 'S', 'G': '47', 'H': '92.8', 'P': '1010', 'S': '33', 'T': '8.7', 'V': '7000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.6', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1200', 'D': 'S', 'G': '48', 'H': '91.4', 'P': '1009', 'S': '33', 'T': '8.8', 'V': '12000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.5', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1260', 'D': 'S', 'G': '47', 'H': '91.5', 'P': '1008', 'S': '34', 'T': '8.7', 'V': '18000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.4', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1320', 'D': 'S', 'G': '46', 'H': '89.0', 'P': '1007', 'S': '33', 'T': '9.0', 'V': '19000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.3', 'Pt': 'F'}, {'$': '1380', 'D': 'S', 'G': '44', 'H': '88.5', 'P': '1006', 'S': '34', 'T': '9.2', 'V': '12000', 'W': '8', 'Dp': '7.4', 'Pt': 'F'}], 'type': 'Day', 'value': '2020-01-01Z'}]  SCOTLAND    EUROPE       4.0
```

What would be the best way to flatten Period column ? is there a better way to achieve desired result?

Thank you.

P.S full json file is at https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5dd39d51e640d94a87e04297bfa1db3d20200909162616/c41164

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use a combination of [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to open the `dicts`
- Use [`.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to explode the `lists` of `dicts`

  - Each `dict` in the list will move to a separate row
- Use `.json_normalize` on the new column of `dicts`
- In regards to the JSON structure

  - Each `'Location'` has a `'Period'`
  - Each `'Period'` is a list of `dicts`.

    - The first `dict` is `'Rep'`, which is a `dict`
    - The second `dict` is also `'Rep'`, but it is a `list` of `dicts`
  - When `'Period'` is normlized, the first `'Rep'` gets expanded into separate columns (`'Rep.$'`, `'Rep.D'`, etc.), but the 2nd `'Rep'` is a column of `NaN` and `lists` of `dicts`.
  - The `lists` of `dicts` in `'Rep'` get exploded, so each `dict` is on a separate row.

    - These `dicts` are then normalized to separate columns (`'$'`, `'D'`, etc.), the column headers are renamed to add `'Rep.'` to the front, and finally, used to fill the `NaNs` in the corresponding columns in dataframe `df`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

# read in the JSON file
with open('metoffice.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# normalize Location
df = pd.json_normalize(data, ['SiteRep', 'DV', 'Location'])

# explode the list of dicts in Period
df = df.explode('Period', ignore_index=True)

# normalize and join Period back to df
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.Period)).drop(columns=['Period'])

# Rep contains NaNs or lists of dicts
# NaN can't be exploded so they must be filled with empty lists
# .fillna([]) does not work
df.Rep = df.Rep.fillna({i: [] for i in df.index})

# explode the lists on Rep 
df = df.explode('Rep', ignore_index=True)

# fillna with {} to use json_normalize
df.Rep = df.Rep.fillna({i: {} for i in df.index})

# normalize Rep
rep = pd.json_normalize(df.Rep)

# add Rep. to beginning of column names in the rep dataframe
rep.columns = [f'Rep.{v}' for v in rep.columns]

# fillna on the the Rep. columns from the rep dataframe and drop the Rep column
df = df.fillna(rep).drop(columns=['Rep'])
```

#### Output of df

- As you can see, there is a row (25: 0-24) for all `'Rep'`, for the first `'Location'`, which matches the JSON file.

```
       i     lat     lon                 name   country continent elevation type        value Rep.$ Rep.D Rep.G Rep.H Rep.P Rep.S Rep.T  Rep.V Rep.W Rep.Dp Rep.Pt
0   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2019-12-31Z  1380    SW    34  79.5  1019    25   7.9  13000     8    4.6      F
1   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z     0    SW    32  84.0  1018    21   7.5  13000     8    5.0      F
2   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z    60    SW    34  81.7  1018    22   7.5  12000     8    4.6      F
3   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   120    SW    36  79.9  1017    24   7.9  11000     8    4.7      F
4   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   180    SW    40  82.3  1016    23   7.5  13000     8    4.7      F
5   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   240    SW    33  84.6  1015    18   8.0  12000     8    5.6      F
6   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   300    SW    33  85.3  1015    24   8.3  11000     8    6.0      F
7   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   360   WSW    41  89.0  1014    30   8.5   8000     8    6.8      F
8   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   420    SW    43  89.6  1013    28   8.7   7000     7    7.1      F
9   3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   480    SW    39  88.4  1013    23   8.7  15000     7    6.9      F
10  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   540    SW    40  84.3  1013    29   9.1  19000     8    6.6      F
11  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   600    SW    41  85.4  1012    24   8.9  12000     8    6.6      F
12  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   660    SW    38  84.2  1012    28   9.2  13000     8    6.7      F
13  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   720    SW    47  83.6  1011    32   9.4  12000     8    6.8      F
14  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   780   WSW    45  84.8  1011    30   9.4  11000     8    7.0      F
15  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   840    SW    43  86.0  1010    28   9.4  11000     7    7.2      F
16  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   900   WSW    40  85.4  1009    29   9.4  12000     8    7.1      F
17  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z   960    SW    39  86.0  1009    25   9.2  11000     8    7.0      F
18  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z  1020    SW    33  87.8  1009    23   8.9  11000     8    7.0      F
19  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z  1080    SW    36  85.5  1008    23   8.9  11000     8    6.6      F
20  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z  1140    SW    40  86.6  1007    28   8.8  14000     8    6.7      F
21  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z  1200   SSW    39  84.8  1006    28   8.8  13000     8    6.4      F
22  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z  1260   SSW    37  87.7  1005    26   8.0  15000     8    6.1      F
23  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z  1320     S    37  88.4  1003    24   8.0  13000     8    6.2      F
24  3002  60.749  -0.854           BALTASOUND  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      15.0  Day  2020-01-01Z  1380     S    38  89.6  1002    29   7.6  11000     8    6.0      F
25  3005  60.139  -1.183  LERWICK (S. SCREEN)  SCOTLAND    EUROPE      82.0  Day  2019-12-31Z  1380     W    41  89.5  1020    28   7.2  15000     8    5.6      F
```

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed explanation of dict  vs lists of dicts.